# Wordpress: jump link not jumping to correct location

Tags: css, wordpress, page-jump

I'm just trying to set up a simple Wordpress.
For some unknown reason, the jump link is not working correctly.

See the link "zwooping" in the following webpage: 
http://zbl.zwoop.be/?page_id=65

As you may notice, the jump distance depends on the current scroll location when I click the link.
Could this be related to the current WP template that I'm using?
Thanks.

Edit:
I didn't add extra code for this.
I defined an anchor with href (the link), then defined an anchor that defines it as the name attribute (the target).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the console of your browser:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Have a closer look at the console. It will show you where you made a programming mistake.

**EDIT:**

Your code looks fine for me. I cannot find a mistake. I created a short **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cnb73/)** which does the same as your code does and it works fine. So I think you should have a closer look to your scripts etc. because I think your code runs in a conflict which calls this mistake that it jumps to the wrong place.

Comment: My mistake, I fixed that. But the problem is the same.

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code? Otherwise it would be difficult to help :)

Comment: Well, the problem is that I didn't add code for this. The jump link in WP just works by adding an href definition, then adding another element with the name of the href. It's the first time I'm using WP.

Comment: Your code looks fine, I cannot find any mistake. But I'm sure I don't see the whole code. I'll edit my answer